# Linear guideway with Ball screw for X, Y ,& Z axes

Tags: diy-3d-printer, linear-motion

I'm building a 3D printer for bio medical application and looking for different opinions on motion system. Build volume 400x300x250 mm

I'm thinking about using Linear guide way with ball screw [Linear guide way with ball screw](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-oem-low-price-40mm-wide-linear-guide-rail-with-motor-and-ball-screw-for/32607755602.html?spm=2114.search0604.3.8.2ba070f976eHAY&s=p&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10059_10696_100031_5017615_10084_10083_10103_451_5017515_452_10618_10307_5017415_5017715,searchweb201603_54,ppcSwitch_2&algo_expid=3220a35f-ec02-4854-862b-b1f201b8ab47-4&algo_pvid=3220a35f-ec02-4854-862b-b1f201b8ab47&priceBeautifyAB=0)

Would this mechanism be good for a 3D printer.

I'm als0 thinking about using [Closed loop stepper motor](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/closed-loop-stepper-motor/) and [Closed loop driver](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/closed-loop-stepper-driver/closed-loop-stepper-driver-0-70a-24-48vdc-for-nema-17-23-24-stepper-motor-cl57t.html)

There'll be two X axes and Y will be mounted on that.
Z axis will be able to move Up and Down

Comment: good is always together with a certain application: as X or Y or Z drive? Do you need to enclose the drive system or not? do you need fast printing or is slow ok? What level of precision you need? All these determine what kind of motion system you need. A rough sketch of the drive system would be nice too - as a note there are 2 common ways that are proven: Core-XY (the bed lowers along Z, the printhead moves in the XY plane) and Portal designs (the bed moves in Y, the printhead on an X gantry, the gantry moves up in Z)

Comment: In my design, Bed is mounted on Z axis, which can Up and Down, and extruder moves X & Y direction. As per the specifications of linear guide way + Ball screw, if I use 1610 ball screw it can reach up to 160 mm/sec.

Comment: That's a Core-XY setup (or similar to it).

Comment: What's your suggesion for using something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-oem-low-price-40mm-wide-linear-guide-rail-with-motor-and-ball-screw-for/32607755602.html?spm=2114.search0604.3.8.2ba070f976eHAY&s=p&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10059_10696_100031_5017615_10084_10083_10103_451_5017515_452_10618_10307_5017415_5017715,searchweb201603_54,ppcSwitch_2&algo_expid=3220a35f-ec02-4854-862b-b1f201b8ab47-4&algo_pvid=3220a35f-ec02-4854-862b-b1f201b8ab47&priceBeautifyAB=0) for X & Y axis